# vertical bar in docstrip file changes to j with unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math, dtx, docstrip

I'm writing a `.dtx` file that can generate multifiles, here is my minimal working example.

```latex
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{my.dtx}[2022/05/17 3.1a mytest]
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<filea|fileb> test
%    \end{macrocode}
```

If there **is** `unicode-math` package, I have output:

[image]

If there **isn't** ·unicode-math` package, I have output:

[image]

We can see that the vertical bar `|` changes to `j` with `unicode-math`. Why would this happen and how to fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wait, I think the point is that tag name cannot contain vertical bar anyway? What's it for?

Comment: Oh never mind, it's valid. Then it's likely some bug/conflict then

Comment: By the way MWE could look like this, although obviously people don't usually write dtx file like that https://pybin.pw/ACuSfhHpMwjKUTJlKfSzvkT3XTZQ (and as you can see the bug is with `ltxdoc` documentclass instead of `docstrip`. (can confirm `doc` also have issue)

Comment: Alright the issue is with the hard coded character codes in macro `\mod@math@codes`. Just redefine it

Comment: Logged as https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/820

Comment: @JosephWright thanks for your log :-)

Answer (score 2):

As partially explained in the comment, the issue is with the `doc` package "hard codes" the math code value for `|`. (which is in turn loaded by `ltxdoc` documentclass)

[image]

Normally the character is in position 6A...

[image: image from encguide.pdf]

As a temporary workaround, you can patch the command...

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}


\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\mod@math@codes}{"226A}{"227C}{}{}
\makeatother

    \begin{macrocode}
        %<filea|&-+:=fileb> test
%    \end{macrocode}    
  
\end{document}
```

Or, if you don't want to fall into the same trap yourself and compute the value dynamically:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set_protected:Npn \definepatchvertmathcode:n #1 {
    \cs_set_protected:Npn \patchvertmathcode {
        \mathcode `\| = #1
    }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \definepatchvertmathcode:n {x}
\definepatchvertmathcode:x {\int_eval:n{
        \mathcode`\| - (\mathcode`\| - "800) / "1000 * "1000 + "2000
}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\mod@math@codes}{\patchvertmathcode}{}{}
\makeatother


    \begin{macrocode}
%<filea|&-+:=fileb> test
%    \end{macrocode}    
  
\end{document}
```

(explanation, the code "replaces" the 4th digit from whatever it was originally to 2 (mathbin class),
by computing the new value to be `0x2000 + a % 0x1000`, where `a%0x1000` is computed as `a-floor(a/0x1000)`, `floor(a/0x1000)` is computed as `round((a-0x800)/0x1000)`, and `a` is the old mathcode of `|`.)

Note that the code must be executed **after begin{document}** as unicode-math setup is only done there.

Remark: the `doc` package is maintained by the LaTeX team, hopefully bugs will be fixed soon.

[image]

Comment: Only bugs that they care about, though. So hopefully they care about this one. (not complaining. I'm not paying anyway.)

Comment: It's a bit complex as `unicode-math` is currently formally Will, although that is under discussion

Comment: Note that although we do try to log issues we 'spot' in questions, it's best to report anything you think is a bug in LaTeX to the tracker

Comment: @user202729 not a real friendly comment I would say; closer to the truth would be "only those that we get around working on". A day over here has only 24 hours and even those can't all be put on LaTeX for others.

Comment: (sigh. can't complain)

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that it should be fixed in the package that changes math setup, i.e., unicode-math in that case, just like such a package needs to adjust other code if it involves math and not the other way around. `doc` has a hook for that since 1992, is it isn't quite fair to claim it "hardwires stuff" it has put that precisely into `\mod@math@codes` so that setups that require a different set can adjust that.

As a workaround that doesn't need etoolbox, `\makeatletter`or other gymnastics, the following would be enough whether or not a document runs with or without unicode-math:

```
\AddToHook{package/unicode-math/after}{%
  \AddToHook{cmd/mod@math@codes/after}{\mathcode`\|="227C }}
```

But I agree, eventually some explicit support should be added to unicode-math, e.g., the inner line of the above.

Comment: Hm? wouldn't that be pretty fragile? (i.e. depends on whatever implementation the target package uses & also that sounds a bit "heavy" if there are lots of packages being "supported" that way, they would all need to be checked) (at least both of them are maintained by the LaTeX team so there are reasonable guarantee here...)

Comment: I guess I can compare it to some C program writing something like `if(ch == 88)` instead of `if(ch == 'X')`, then fails on some (theoretical) computer in the future that does not use ASCII/Unicode etc..

Comment: @user202729 in what way fragile? I said workaround for the OP. It only applies to to the case unicode-math is loaded and does nothing if not, ie the same as your first solution but restricted to the scenario that unicode-math is around. I agree, one could make doc compute the right values dynamically, but then you have the issue when to do that. Given that unicode-math changes them late you need to do that even later or redo it again and again.

Comment: No, the fragile part refer to the other suggestion that unicode-math patches doc's macro because it kind of depend on the inner macro in doc being named exactly mod@math@codes? (not sure if there's a better way either. Originally there are "public interface" like \alpha then unicode-math can redefine them, but there isn't really any such "public interface" for mathbin | so far ... perhaps there's the way of defining it to be "8000 → `\mathbin{\vert}` at some performance cost)

Comment: well, that is the kind of "interface level" that was around in 1992, so yes, it is internal because not everybody should mess with it, but it was meant (and documented) as an interface to be changed when the font layout changes. The assumption being that this is only needed for very very few scenarios (which turned out to be true -- unicode math 20odd years later being one of them.